# Fixed Time Step in Game Loop

Tags: java, time

I have this game loop:

```
public void show() {

        // other stuff...

        // set delta time
        float currentTime = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        float dt = currentTime - lastTime;

        // iterate through entities
        for (Entity e : entities) {
            e.draw();
            e.update(dt);
        }

        // other stuff...

        lastTime = currentTime;
    }
```

How would I implement a fixed time step for the update process? That is, how can I update my process based on a constant fps (not updating every time the loop runs?) I know I'll just iterate through entities twice (one for update, one for draw), but how would I fix a time step for the update process?

Comment: Okay, I'm lost (not that hard).  What's a "fixed time step"?  Do you want to maintain a constant fps by generating a variable sleep period after each update cycle??

Comment: Yes, I'll update my post. I don't need to update every single time the loop runs, only at a certain time.

Comment: How would I use that to update the entities every few seconds, but render every iteration of the loop?

Comment: He's the thing, you probably don't want to render on each iteration of the loop.  Update/render/wait, repeat...

Comment: You should use a scheduled executor (or a timer) to schedule a *task* to be done every some seconds (or years... your call). For periodic GUI tasks a SwingTimer is preferred, however.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using multiple Threads, if you can:

you'll want a separate class containing a clock on which to call a frame update. For structure purposes, you might want this class to create an instance of the window class.

```
public void run(){
    for(;;){
        Thread.sleep([milleseconds between frames]);
        [graphic class].nextFrame();
    }
}
```

If you need it, here's a tutorial on Threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html